# Problema con múltiples pestañas y el SessionAttribute

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring

Tengo una aplicación desarrollada en Spring MVC y en cada controlador le meto como SessionAttribute su respectivo formulario para poder ir haciendo redirect en cada método y conservar la misma url independientemente de lo que haga (siempre redirijo a la url que carga la plantilla). El caso es que no habia caido hasta ahora que si abro 2 pestañas, la primera no funcionará correctamente (ya que el SessionAttribute será el último que haya cargado, osea el de la última pestaña).

Googleando un poco he conseguido encontrar una solución que podréis ver [aquí](http://duckranger.com/2012/11/add-conversation-support-to-spring-mvc/) (en inglés), el problema es que después de implementarla ahora cada vez que intento cargar el SessionAttribute desde cualquier sitio, me dice que no existe. Aquí os dejo la traza:

> org.springframework.web.HttpSessionRequiredException: Expected session
>   attribute 'customSearch'  at
>   org.springframework.web.method.annotation.ModelFactory.initModel(ModelFactory.java:103)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:722)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:686)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:80)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:925)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:856)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:936)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:827)
>     at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:622)     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:812)
>     at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:291)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:88)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:108)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:84)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:118)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:84)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:113)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:103)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:113)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.authentication.rememberme.RememberMeAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(RememberMeAuthenticationFilter.java:139)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:54)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:45)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:183)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:105)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:87)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:192)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:160)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:343)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:260)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:219)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:142)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:617)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:518)
>     at
>   org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1091)
>     at
>   org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:668)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:279)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Y por aquí un trozo de código de un controlador para que os hagais una idea:

```
@SessionAttributes("customSearch")
@Controller
@Transactional
public class SimpleSearchController {

   @RequestMapping(value = "home/search/{numPage}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String searchNew(Model model) {

        model.addAttribute("customSearch", new CustomSearchForm(true));

        return "redirect:/search";
    }
    @RequestMapping(value = "/search", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String searchGo(@ModelAttribute("customSearch") CustomSearchForm searchForm,
            Model model, Errors errors) {
         //logica necesaria
         model.addAttribute("customSearch", searchForm);
         return "search/search";
     }
}
```

Comment: ¿Puedes explicar cuál es el problema que tienes que resolver (tu use case o requerimiento) y por qué crees que esta idea es la mejor?

Comment: _Micro-Tip_: Es recomendable usar `@Transactional` en la capa de **servicio** (negocio) - [Lectura](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1079114/where-does-the-transactional-annotation-belong)

Comment: @jasilva eso depende. Hay artículos donde explican que lo mejor es abrir la transacción en un filtro antes de que se procese la petición y la cierre al finalizar el manejo de la petición. Esa parte del diseño depende en realidad para el tipo de aplicaciones que se realizan. La segunda respuesta más votada a esa pregunta es de dos años más hacia adelante y considera buenos puntos que `@duffymo` en su momento no trató.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza el problema que tengo que resolver es el que el usuario pueda abrir multiples pestañas y trabajar en ellas simultaneamente, vamos que el problema principal es que al abrir otra pestaña el navegador duplica la sesión por lo que tanto si accede a un nuevo controlador como si permanece en el mismo, se quedará con el que haya hecho la última petición.

Comment: Lo que describes me parece un efecto que no consideraste al plantear tu propuesta de solución. Lo que encuentro al leer tu pregunta es el problema XY, es decir, describes un problema X que en realidad es un problema de una propuesta de solución para un problema Y. Mi pregunta va hacia cuál es tu problema Y, cuál es el requerimiento de usuario o de negocio que debes satisfacer, que lo has estado haciendo guardando unos datos en sesión es parte de tu solución.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza La verdad es que no tengo claro si he entendido bien lo que acabas de poner xD, lo que tengo que resolver a toda costa es que el usuario sea capaz de abrir varias pestañas y trabajar en ellas, a la vez que las variables que guardo en sesión sigan en sus respectivos lugares. En otras palabras, generar sesiones distintas para cada pestaña. La aplicación ya tiene un tiempo, con lo que los SessionAttributes llevan bastante ahí, el intento de solución viene al intentar aplicar lo descrito en el link que hay en la pregunta.

Comment: Lo que quiero saber es cuál es el problema de fondo a resolver. Tú dices que tu problema es mantener sesiones por pestañas o tabs del navegador, lo cual es **imposible** a menos que modifiques el código de cada browser, lo compiles y lo distribuyas a todos los usuarios de tu aplicación. Por ello, yo creo que tienes más un problema de diseño en la aplicación al utilizar atributos de sesión (los cuales son muy usualmente mal utilizados).

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza es lo que entendí que hacia el link que enlacé, quizá lo entendiera (o lo expresara) mal, pero ahí parece que daban una solución al problema de las pestañas, de todas formas, cual podría ser la mejor forma de solucionar esto? quitando los atributos de sesion y los redirects?

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/37121/discussion-between-luiggi-mendoza-and-raider).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basado en la descripción de tu problema y [la conversación vía chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/37121/discussion-between-luiggi-mendoza-and-raider) lo mejor sería que utilices un caché de los objetos con los que interactúas. De esta manera, tus operaciones contra base de datos serán menores y tendrás mejor rendimiento al momento de obtener los datos a mostrar en tus peticiones GET. Una solución de caché es utilizar librerías existentes para ello cono EhCache o dependiendo de tus necesidades puedes utilizar Hazelcast u otros.

Respecto al conversation scope que mencionas, te recomiendo no utilizarlo puesto que es muy frágil. Depende mucho de un parámetro que pasa vía query string, y si algún usuario cambia su valor entonces rompe el control que tienes en esa pestaña.